# What is a suitable pattern for building a web/mobile app that leverages ether?

Tags: contract-design, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, light-clients, mobile-wallet

Noob to ether dev.

Looking to understand how to build an app that leverages Ethereum - what suitable patterns are out there (ideally to go via some tutorials).

A few apps examples (from easy to complicated) that I would think would be supported but I'm not sure the architecture that makes the most sense for the platform:

- Simple app (mobile, web, and/or desktop) that allows a user to pay a bit of ether to take a message, hash it, and put the result on the blockchain for all to see (and more importantly, verify that something was known/sent at a particular time)
- Service app that takes emails and does similar to the above (I'd think both would batch) - giving strong assurances (via the blockchain) that someone wrote something or other at some particular time (e.g. useful in contract negotiation)
- Complex app that would allow for binding arbitration - agreeing on a pool of arbitrators based on reputation, putting up crypto to pay the arbitration fees, and (possibly) putting up crypto for the arbitration to be self-executing. Most of this could be via a front end but blockchain would make all of it independently verifiable.

Again, I'm quite new but it seems to even get a wallet and some gas that one could use on a mobile device or pay via an app (like one can with AliPay/WeChat) is not a  capability that exists now. Given this, what would appropriate development architectures/patterns for the above apps be?